# Angular Unit Test "The pipe 'currency' could not be found"

Tags: angular, unit-testing

[In this GitHub repo](https://github.com/xxlxii/tapp) a simple Angular 12 application can be found exhibiting the following behavior: during `npm test`, the unit test `Router: App > should navigate to /one` failed with `"Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0302: The pipe 'currency' could not be found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302"` occurs whereas `npm start` the error doesn't occurr. Something tells me I have to do something with the `Router: App > should navigate to /one` unit test configuation, but I have read and tried several suggestions found on Internet with no success.

Comment: Add `CommonModule` to your imports in app.routing.module.spec.ts

Comment: Thank you Sham. I did, but still not working.

Comment: Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes: the same `Error: NG0302: The pipe 'currency' could not be found!` Maybe you can `git clone` the project and take a look at it. I would be very glad to know how it go.

Comment: Angular unit tests have their own scope. So each `spec.ts` file is a standalone "environment" where you have to mock the dependencies of the class you're testing. Also eg if you're using `routerLink` in the unit, you need to import the `RouterTestingModule` in the specfile

Comment: Thank you Pieterjan. That's how I got it configured: in the only `.spec.ts` file I have to test routing, I am using `RouterTestingModule` in `imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)]`. Nothing seems to be working to resolve the error.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you declare AppComponent. You don't need to do that since you're already using `TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent)`

Comment: That was it! Thank you Sham!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to tag people in the comment fields, otherwise they don't get a notification. I had to look at all my recent activity and look at my latest comment here to see that you responded to my comment. :) Not a big deal, but can be good for your to know in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import {CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ YourComponent, CurrencyPipe]
})
```

Comment: Thank you Jaidson. I did that, still doesn't work. Along with Sham suggestion above, I have also tweaked to disable the `enableIvy` compilation (based on some other answers and something that I prefer to do even if it worked because it didn't either). The interesting part is that, as my initial post, it doesn't work in unit testing, not in 'production' (so to speak).

Comment: Man, I made a test your repository, the error is other...

Answer (score 0):

For a made-in unit test navigator, you need to create a spyOn of instance Router.

**app.routing.module.spec.ts**

```
it('should navigate to /one', (() => {
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate'); //create spy
    router.navigate(['/one']);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/one']);
  }));
```

[image]

[image]